# Return different datatypes in a method in java

Tags: java, list, methods

I have a very silly question in java. I have a main method which in turns calls a method passing one string value. But in return I need to get 3 string values. Can someone please assist?

In main method, I pass only one string value and it has to return 3 string or may be at times 2 string and one int.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <String> ls= cusmethod("string1");
        ls.get(0); //get string A
}

Private static string cusmethod(String test)
{
    String A = "A"+test;
    String B = "B"+test;
    String C = "C"+test;

    // Need to return all these 3 string to main method.
    return A , B, C;
}
```

The method should return the 3 string values to the main method. Please advise how to achieve this. I am not sure how to return these strings to main method and how to retrieve these string in main

Comment: It looks like you are already aware of `List<String>`. Why don't you return a `List<String>` in your method?

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a list in your helper method:

```
private static List<String> cusmethod(String test) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A" + test);
    list.add("B" + test);
    list.add("C" + test);

    return list;
}
```

Comment: > or may be at times 2 string and one int

Comment: Thanks for your response. this custom method will need to return a set each time i call.  say, [stringa, stringb,stringc],[stringa1, stringb1,stringc1],[stringa2, stringb2,stringc2]. how can i achieve this now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why did you suddenly change your requirement from returning a list to returning a set?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return more then one value in java. You can wrap your result in a class and return that class.

If you need to return *n* values of the same type you can create a *List* or an array and return that.

You can create a class which hold this 3 string and return that class, like ...

```
class String3 {
    private String res1;
    private String res2;
    private String res3;
    public String3(String res1, String res2, String res3) {
        super();
        this.res1 = res1;
        this.res2 = res2;
        this.res3 = res3;
    }
    public String getRes1() {
        return res1;
    }
    public String getRes2() {
        return res2;
    }
    public String getRes3() {
        return res3;
    }
}
```

Then you can use your Custom class like this.

```
private String3 method(String test) {
    String a = "A"+test;
    String b = "B"+test;
    String c = "C"+test;

    // Need to return all these 3 string to main method.
    return new String3(a, b, c);    
}
```

You can use a library like [vavr](https://www.vavr.io) to return a *tuple*.

```
Tuple3<String, String, String> result = Tuple.of(A, B, C);
```

The best option is to re-evaluate your code to see how you should do that in java.

You are trying use a solution that is not idiomatic in java, you should try to see how to decompose your problem in a *java idiomatic* way, not trying to apply solution which are typical of other languages, in the long run it will pay off.

Answer (score 0):

> and it has to return 3 strings or may be at times 2 strings and one int

In Java you can use `Object` type to represent any object, for example:

```
public void foo(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof String){  // obj is a String
        System.out.println("Hello, " + (String) obj);
    }
    else if(obj instanceof Integer) {  // obj is an integer value
        // Integer is an object analog of int, because int is a primitive type
        int my_int = (Integer) obj;  // but we can implicitly convert Integer to int
        System.out.println("I doubled your integer: " + my_int * 2);
    }

}

// somewhere
foo("Steve");  // Hello, Steve
foo(2);  // I doubled your integer: 4
```

So in your case you can return List of Objects:

```
private static List<Object> cusmethod(String test)
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if(test.equals("return 3 strings")){
        list.add("A" + test);
        list.add("B" + test);
        list.add("C" + test);
    }
    else if(test.equals("return 2 strings and an int")){
        list.add("A" + test);
        list.add("B" + test);
        list.add(12345);
    }
    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List <Object> ls = cusmethod("string1");
    String s = (String) ls.get(0); //get string A
    int x = (Integer) ls.get(2);
}
```